# The non-nullable local variable 'result' must be assigned before it can be used Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

I am taking Angela Yu's Flutter and Dart course and it is very outdated and I am getting a lot of errors.

This is an async await demo and the syntax has changed since she made the course. I have tried several ways but can never get the same response to what Angela gets in her videos.

The issue is in the result variable in the task2() function. It needs for me to assign it a value for it to work but when I do I still dont get the same response as her.

I have tried putting late before the task 2 string result, assigning it a value of an empty string '' and marking it as nullable with a question mark after and none of these work. I have attached my code plus an image of the output Angela is getting.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
[image: Angela Yu's code]

[image: My result]

```
`void main() {
  performTasks();
}

void performTasks() async {
  task1();
  String task2Result = await task2();
  print(task2());
  task3(task2Result);
}

void task1() {
  String result = 'task 1 data';
  print('Task 1 complete');
}

Future<String> task2() async {
  Duration threeSeconds = Duration(seconds: 3);

  late String result;

  await Future.delayed(threeSeconds, () {
    result = 'task 2 data biatch';
    print('Task 2 complete');
  });

  return result;
}

void task3(String task2data) {
  String result = 'task 3 data';
  print('Task 3 complete with $task2data');
}`
```

Comment: There should not be anything wrong with your implementation of the `task2` function.  Even your screenshots show that your program ran without error, so it's unclear what problem you're actually having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replicate the result shown on the course video, you would need to remove the `print(task2())` line from your `performTasks` function. `task2` is a `Future` so you will be printing the instance information instead of the `Future` result. Furthermore, that would call the `task2` function again and make the 'Task 2 complete' message gets printed twice.

The final code of your `performTasks` function should look like this:

```dart
void performTasks() async {
  task1();
  String task2Result = await task2();
  task3(task2Result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated to both of you!

Comment: Later on she added Future and has spoke about it more, but your response helps me understand the issue in more detail so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see the images but by reading your code I see you are missing `await` keyword before task2 like this `print(await task2());`

since task2 is **future** you need to wait for the result.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated to both of you!